# module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'python'

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn as learn

home/michael/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219:
RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module  
'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime 
version 3.6
return f(*args, **kwds)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-630a74eb6a34> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn as learn

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn' has no attribute 'python'
```

I am trying to import this library in jupyter in linux environment, and I could not find any answer on google.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the module `tensorflow.contrib.learn` reimports everything from `tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn`:

```
 91 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
 92 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
 93 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
 94 
 95 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner_lib as learn_runner
```

So you can just import it directly:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn
```

or

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
```